# Seaborn Boxplot - axis color and width

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, boxplot

I am using seaborn to create boxplots. How can I modify axis line thickness and color?

[image: [seaborn boxplots axis line thickness]]

I don't know where in my code I can fix this issue. I need to change x-axis color and width to make it blue and thicker....

thanks

```
plt.figure()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(45,35), dpi=150)
font_size_axes=128
label_font_size=128
ax = sns.boxplot(x=group, y=strain_lable[:], data=table,order=data_order,   palette=my_pal, width=0.3, 
             fliersize=50, linewidth=12)
```

Comment: two comments: are you sure you need to have a plot that's 45x35 inches? And also, you seem to be creating two figures for no reason?

Comment: plt.figure() is not needed. that was a mistake as I copied a part of the code. I need really high quality figures as they should not be pixelated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(5)
ax.spines['left'].set_color('orange')
```

If you need to color all the spines, you can loop through:

```
for _,s in ax.spines.items():
    s.set_linewidth(5)
    s.set_color('cyan')
```

If you would like to make these changes for a bunch of plots, you might considering changing the rc file (see ["Customizing matplotlib"](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)). The relevant properties are `'axes.linewidth'` and `'axes.edgecolor'`